# Pharse level dependency parser using java,nlp

Tags: java, dependency-injection, nlp, stanford-nlp

Can someone please elaborate on how to obtain " pharse level dependency" using the Stanfords's Natural Language Processing Lexical Parser- open source Java code?
http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/nutch/branches/branch-1.2/src/plugin/lib-http/src/java/org/apache/nutch/protocol/http/api/RobotRulesParser.java

http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/sql-comparison/

such as

pharse               dependency

The accident --------->happened

falling    ---------> as

the night ---------->falling

as such as many more...

Thanks!

Comment: i am getting word level dependency using stanford dependency parsing , but i want the pharse level dependency

Comment: As in: "The cat is green. It is nice, too"  - would output that 'It' refers to cat?

Comment: @KenstonChoi i have edited the question with example.thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can group the words in one token, so you can get phrase-level dependency. At the very least, this covers multi-word expressions (MWE) and named-entities. This can also increase the accuracy (particularly for grouping named-entities as one token) during dependency parsing.

In your example, on determiners being grouped together, what I think you can do is to post-process them. After getting the dependency parse tree , you can add "the" to "accident". You can base it from the constituent parse tree if you want,

```
(NP (DT The) (NN accident))
```

looking at those that belongs to the same noun phrase or other phrases. Not quite sure how this will be useful, or what issues may arise from this approach. You can do some experiments using [Stanford parser](http://nlp.stanford.edu/software/lex-parser.shtml) ([demo](http://nlp.stanford.edu:8080/parser/index.jsp)).

Comment: then how to define the dependency word with origin word.and i have done stanford parser.

Comment: What do you mean by "defining"? Are you referring to my first suggestion? or to the post-process suggestion?

Comment: it means the who words properly defining the relation in sentence along pharse level

Comment: @RajdeoKumar, can you restate/elaborate your comments?