# Combining nn tags to form noun phrases using Java

Tags: java, nlp, stanford-nlp

How to combine all nn tags to a phrase tag using Java

```
nsubj(martyrdom-4, Today-1)
cop(martyrdom-4, is-2)
det(martyrdom-4, the-3)
root(ROOT-0, martyrdom-4)
nn(Mukherjee-7, Dr-6)
prep_of(martyrdom-4, Mukherjee-7)
det(founder-9, the-8)
dep(tribute-17, founder-9)

prep_of(founder-9, Jan-11)
nn(body-15, Sangh-12)
nn(body-15, BJP-13)
nn(body-15, parent-14)
dep(tribute-17, body-15)
poss(tribute-17, My-16)
dep(martyrdom-4, tribute-17)
prep_to(tribute-17, him-19)
```

I want to get a noun phrase:

```
prep_of(founder-9,Jan-11)
nn(body-15, Sangh-12)
nn(body-15, BJP-13)
nn(body-15, parent-14)
```

The output should be----------> jan sangh BJP parent

Comment: Related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11985585/pharse-level-dependency-parser-using-java-nlp/

Comment: @KenstonChoi ya little bits same but the question you indicated is asking for dependency not noun pharse.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is the dependency chain output from Stanford Parser. If yes, then you should already have the noun phrases (NP nodes) in the parsed tree of the sentence. You can extract the lowest level NP nodes from the parse tree to get the required noun phrases. For example, for the sentence "*Today is the martyrdom of Dr. Mukherjee, founder of Jan Sangh BJP.*", the parse tree would be:

```
(ROOT
  (S
    (NP (NNP Today))
    (VP (VBZ is)
      (NP
        (NP (DT the) (NN martyrdom))
        (PP (IN of)
          (NP
            (NP (NNP Dr.) (NNP Mukherjee))
            (, ,)
            (NP
              (NP (NN founder))
              (PP (IN of)
                (NP (NNP Jan) (NNP Sangh) (NNP BJP))))))))
    (. .)))
```

In this tree, the lowest level NPs containing proper nouns (NNPs) will give you most (all of them not being the named entities that you need) of the noun phrases that you need. In this case the output will be:

```
(NP (NNP Today))
(NP (NNP Dr.) (NNP Mukherjee))
(NP (NNP Jan) (NNP Sangh) (NNP BJP))
```

Comment: how we traverse the graph tree using java